# Combine multiple flow file attributes of different flow files as a single attribute in Nifi

Tags: apache-nifi

I have a specific requirement, which is to combine attributes of different flow files and add it as a single attribute, for example let's consider I am having 2 flow files FF-1 and FF-2. in FF-1 I am having an attribute called **object_name** and its value is **nifi-1234** and for FF-2 I am having the same attribute with a different value like **nifi-2345**. Now I need to concatenate these two attributes like **object_name** = **nifi-1234/nifi-2345** as a single attribute.Need help in doing this through nifi.

Comment: what about flowfiles content - you want to join it as well from 2 files into one?